# Debugging Issue in UFT 12.54 for IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, hp-uft

I am using UFT 12.54 on IE 11. Whenever I debug my script on the web application using F11(Step Into), the webpage goes one page back.
Please Suggest.

Comment: Hard to tell what the issue is, but you can try these things: Install [Microsoft Debugger](https://community.softwaregrp.com/t5/UFT-Practitioners-Forum/HP-UFT-Download-and-install-Script-Debugger-Error/td-p/246565) if its not installed, Run a repair on UFT.

Comment: Are you talking about debugging the test-script (in UFT) or the web-script (in IE)?

Comment: Yes, debugging the test scrip in UFT.

Comment: Got it fixed, the debugger had some issues.
Thanks!!